# My.Computer.Name Results in Run-time Error 424

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

Need to use My.Computer.Name on an Access form but it results in a 424 run-time error ("Requires object"). I copied and pasted example code for My.Computer.Name from Microsoft's Office Dev website which generates the same run-time error. I also tried My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists with the same result.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/how-can-i-get-computer-name-using-access-2007-vba/aa5471c7-f06c-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?tab=MoreHelp

Basically, use either

```
'more simple but easier to "spoof"
Environ("computername")

'Should use as long as it works on your Access server
'Simply call "ComputerName()" whenever you need to get the user's computer
Private Declare Function GetComputerName Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetComputerNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByRef nSize As Long) As Long
Function ComputerName() As String
  Dim stBuff As String * 255
  Dim lAPIResult As Long
  Dim lBuffLen As Long
  lBuffLen = 255
  lAPIResult = GetComputerName(stBuff, lBuffLen)
  If lBuffLen > 0 Then
    ComputerName = Left(stBuff, lBuffLen)
  End If
End Function
```